# Vue.js component within inline component

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I've got this code in `Vue.js 2.0`:

```
<forums inline-template v-cloak>
    <div v-if="!loading">
        <div v-if="!validation.isEmpty(forums)">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-md-4 table__title">
                            Topic
                        </th>

                        <th class="col-md-2 table__title">
                            Bericht
                        </th>

                        <th class="col-md-3 hidden-xs hidden-sm table__title">
                            Laatste
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr @click="link(forum)" v-for="(forum, index) in forums">
                        <td class="col-md-4">
                            @{{ forum.name }}
                            <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                                <p>
                                    <i class="table__subtitle">@{{ forum.description }}</i>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </td>

                        <td class="col-md-2">
                            @{{ forum.messages_count }}
                        </td>

                        <td class="col-md-3 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                            @{{ latestMessageAuthor(forum) }}
                        </td>

                        @if(Auth::user()->isAdmin())
                            <td class="col-md-2 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                                <i class="material-icons" @click.stop="destroy(forum)">
                                    &#xE872;
                                </i>

                                <a :href="'/bewerk/forum/' + forum.slug">
                                    <i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i>
                                </a>

                                <i class="material-icons" @click.stop="increment(forum, index)">
                                    &#xE316;
                                </i>

                                <i class="material-icons" @click.stop="decrement(forum, index)">
                                    &#xE313;
                                </i>
                            </td>
                        @endif

                        <subscription :context="forum.subscriptions_count" :service="service"></subscription>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div v-else>
            <p class="text-center">Geen forums.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="center" v-else>
        <loader :loading="loading"></loader>
    </div>
</forums>
```

The problem is that I receive this error in my console:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "forum" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. 
(found in <Forums> at /Users/Code/forumv2/resources/assets/js/components/forum/forums.vue)
```

I pass the `forum.subscriptions_count` to my `subscription` component. Here it goes wrong. Forum is undefined?

Why is that because it's in a `v-for="(forum, index)"` loop! Does this not work with `inline templates`?

Comment: Share the <subscription> component code. how do you know that's the issue? in the code you are defining a :context variable, and inside suscription are you using a forum variable?

Comment: Also code of parent component of subscription would be useful to provide answer.